# Why is Grails (6.0.0) trying to cast a String URL parameter to a domain object? (It seems related to a partial match of the domain name.)

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I have a controller method that takes a String argument called "search":

```
def test(String search) {
   log.info("search: ${search}")
   render("testing ${search}")
}
```

This worked fine in Grails 3.3.9, but in 6.0.0, I get an error when my URL includes
`?search=mystring`

Cannot cast object 'mystring' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'com.whatever.project.SavedSearch'

I do have a domain object called SavedSearch. It appears that Grails is attempting to cast the parameter named "search" into an object of this type.

When I change the name of the parameter to anything else, like "searchString", it works fine.

Here are steps to reproduce using a minimal Grails 6 project:

```
git clone https://github.com/landydan/so-grails-6-poc-search-query.git

git checkout revised

grails clean

grails run-app

Navigate in the browser to localhost:8080. 
Click on the link shown in the landing page.  
You should see the class cast exception.
```

Note that this bug seems to depend on the presence of the method below that references the SavedSearch object, in the same controller:

```
    def something() {
        Long searchId = params.id as Long
        // below is the line that needs to be present
        SavedSearch search = SavedSearch.read(searchId)
        render("placeholder")
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I tried to replicate explained behaviour but can not: https://github.com/majkelo/so-grails-6-poc-search-query Could you provide your PoC project? Apparently we need more information

Comment: Thank you @Michal_Szulc for your response.  I figured out that there needs to be another method in the controller, which is below and in the branch I forked at
 
https://github.com/landydan/so-grails-6-poc-search-query/tree/revised 

I also needed to replace your build.gradle with mine, because it wasn't working for me for some reason.  I'd be interested to know whether or not you see the error if you just drop the method below into the controller in your original code, in which case there must be something related to one of the dependencies.

Comment: Here is the method I added to SearchingController.  Apparently it is the reference to the SavedSearch object that causes the problem (in the original "test" method, which is weird).


        def something() {
            Long searchId = params.id as Long
            // below is the line that needs to be present
            SavedSearch search = SavedSearch.read(searchId)
            render("placeholder")
        }

Comment: Sorry, the code markdown doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: @Dan_L please edit your initial question and add details about your PoC repository and add step by step instruction how to replicate your issue

Comment: Thanks for your guidance @Michal_Szulc.  I have made the edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issues after migration. If you have another method where you assign values to variable with the same name as variable in your method, for example:

```
def test(String search) {
   log.info("search: ${search}")
   render("testing ${search}")
}

def another() {
    SavedSearch search = SavedSearch.read(searchId)
}
```

Grails 5/6 will try to use any "search" in method declaration as SavedSearch type. This happens for domains and for command objects.

This is obviously a bug in Grails, but there is simple workaround - just name your variable differently, for example:

`SavedSearch savedSearch = SavedSearch.read(searchId)`

Comment: Thanks  -- I'm glad to get confirmation that there isn't something weird about my configuration.  Yes, I can change variable names -- it will just be a pain to hunt down all the places where this might be occurring in all my controllers.  I will probably try to write a script to parse out the controller method parameters and then search the rest of the file for variables with the same name.  I will file a bug report with Grails.

Comment: I recommend doing integration tests for endpoints, for us it was easy to find all problems as we already had such tests.